# How to automatically start mysql after server restart (CentOS + other distros)?

Tags: linux, mysql, init.d

How would I configure my CentOS Linux server to automatically start mysql when the server is started following a shutdown?

I'm aware of the init.d path...

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d
```

...and I can see mysqld in this folder. I believe that placing items (i.e. by symbolic link) in this folder means that they should start on server restart.

But this did not happen for me.

**Background**

Our central IT desk restarted our virtualised CentOS servers over the weekend. The server was available following restart but the MySQL database had not restarted also.

Thoughts?

Comment: some answers relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859381/how-make-mysql-start-automatically-linux-cli-only

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [chkconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig):

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on
```

Comment: +1 Thanks BUT should this be chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on NOT chkconfig --levels 345 mysqld on ? http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html I tried both. I'm guessing it worked by there was no message or anything, after typing it, I just got another prompt. Any way to tell if it makes mysql restart automatically?

Comment: @Rob:  run `chkconfig --list mysqld` to show what runlevels that init script is set for.

Comment: Couldn't get `chkconfig` installed.... `Package 'chkconfig' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 2):

To enable mysql service on startup, use following command.

```
systemctl enable mysqld.service
```

It will create appropriate symbolic link for you.